# Error starting ApplicationContext in Spring when add @OneToOne Annotation

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea

:
I am a beginner in Java Spring MVC and I want to create a simple program using spring boots.
But I have a problem:
When I add @OneToOne and @JoinColumn to my model class, the project doesn't start!
Error:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2020-05-24 15:24:45.140
>   ERROR 5368 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
>   : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'homeController' defined in file
>   [C:\Users\HamidS\Desktop\application\target\classes\crud\example\application\Controller\HomeController.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'bookServices' defined in file
>   [C:\Users\HamidS\Desktop\application\target\classes\crud\example\application\Services\Service\BookServices.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [crud/example/application/config.class]: Bean instantiation
>   via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method
>   'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on
>   crud.example.application.Models.Book.lessons references an unknown
>   entity: crud.example.application.Models.lesson    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   crud.example.application.Application.main(Application.java:10)
>   ~[classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'bookServices' defined in file
>   [C:\Users\HamidS\Desktop\application\target\classes\crud\example\application\Services\Service\BookServices.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [crud/example/application/config.class]: Bean instantiation
>   via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method
>   'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on
>   crud.example.application.Models.Book.lessons references an unknown
>   entity: crud.example.application.Models.lesson    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   ... 20 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [crud/example/application/config.class]: Bean instantiation
>   via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method
>   'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on
>   crud.example.application.Models.Book.lessons references an unknown
>   entity: crud.example.application.Models.lesson    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   ... 34 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method
>   'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on
>   crud.example.application.Models.Book.lessons references an unknown
>   entity: crud.example.application.Models.lesson    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   ... 48 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or
>   @ManyToOne on crud.example.application.Models.Book.lessons references
>   an unknown entity: crud.example.application.Models.lesson     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:97)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1786)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1730)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1617)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:727)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   crud.example.application.config.sessionFactory(config.java:18)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   crud.example.application.config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2bb57076.CGLIB$sessionFactory$0()
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   crud.example.application.config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2bb57076$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ce3a25e0.invoke()
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
>   ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   crud.example.application.config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2bb57076.sessionFactory()
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   ... 49 common frames
>   omitted
>
> 2020-05-24 15:24:45.140  WARN 5368 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close
>   ApplicationContext
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/admin/SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' parameter 1; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.core.env.Environment'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations: {}     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:245)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:197)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:134)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.availability.AvailabilityChangeEvent.publish(AvailabilityChangeEvent.java:81)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.availability.AvailabilityChangeEvent.publish(AvailabilityChangeEvent.java:67)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.doClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:167)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:978)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:814)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   crud.example.application.Application.main(Application.java:10)
>   ~[classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.core.env.Environment'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations: {}     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1716)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1272)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   ... 23 common frames
>   omitted

*Notice :*  My project worked well with a single model and CRUD operations for The model(Book), But now I want to add a new column (@OneToOne) to the model that the project can't start

My Book Model :

```java
package crud.example.application.Models;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Book")
public class Book
{
    public Book(){}
    public Book(String bookName, String authorName, String count, String writeDate) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.authorName = authorName;
        this.count = count;
        this.writeDate = writeDate;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String bookName;
    @Column
    private String authorName;
    @Column
    private String count;
    @Column
    private String writeDate;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lessonID")
    private lesson lessons;

    public lesson getLessons() {
        return lessons;
    }

    public void setLessons(lesson lessons) {
        this.lessons = lessons;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }

    public String getAuthorName() {
        return authorName;
    }

    public void setAuthorName(String authorName) {
        this.authorName = authorName;
    }

    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getWriteDate() {
        return writeDate;
    }

    public void setWriteDate(String writeDate) {
        this.writeDate = writeDate;
    }
}
```

My Lesson Model :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "lesson")
public class lesson {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public lesson(){}
    public lesson (String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My Hibernate.cfg.xml:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/test?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">123321</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">20</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>


    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

My Configuration Class:

```java
@Configuration
public class config {

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(){
        SessionFactory sf = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Book.class).
                buildSessionFactory();
        return sf;
    }
}
```

i am using IntelliJ IDE.
please help me.
thanks..:D

Comment: try naming your lesson class as Lesson.java, and the class name too, Lesson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the name of Lesson class to uppercase and try changing your SessionFactory bean to

```
   @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(){
        SessionFactory sf = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration()
                           .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                           .addAnnotatedClass(Book.class)
                           .addAnnotatedClass(Lesson.class)
                           .buildSessionFactory();
        return sf;
    }
```

Comment: wow,great, it's working correctly.
but i have a question:
why create lesson model to uppercase?

Comment: It's just a Java naming convention, to have the class/interface name in uppercase and object, method, variable, etc. names in  CamelCase. 
In my opinion, it also helps to enhance the code readability, as 
Lesson lesson=new Lesson() 
clearly separates the class and the object, unlike
lesson lesson=new lesson()

Comment: More about the naming conventions https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions